# How to use wildcards (%) on the database variable rather than the inputted parameter in a query?

Tags: mysql, spring-data-jpa

I know you can use wildcards on the parameter in a query like:

```
SELECT a FROM Year a WHERE a.name LIKE %:name%;
```

and in that query if a.name = 'first' and :name = 'fir', that would be a match.

What I need is the opposite. Users might type 'first.' (with a space, or a comma, or a typo) and I need it to be a match. I need to use the wildcard % in the database variable.

I tried using the wildcard directly on the variable like:

```
SELECT a FROM Year a WHERE '%' + a.name + '%' LIKE :name;
```

and also:

```
SELECT a FROM Year a WHERE %a.name% LIKE :name;
```

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `CONCAT`:

```
SELECT a.* FROM Year a WHERE :name LIKE CONCAT('%',a.name, '%');
```